# visual studio 2013 indent new lines expression and lambdas

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

In visual studio 2013 when I write new line in lambda, then have following

```
taskData.ForEach(p =>
                            {
                                //smth
                            });
```

curly braces are automatically on the right side. How to meake braces will be automatically on left side:

```
taskData.ForEach(p =>
            {
                //smth
            });
```

Comment: Check Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Formatting

Comment: I can't find what parameter is responsible for this behaviour.

Comment: All the options that could affect that are in that section.  Experiment with them to find out what they all do.  That way, you won't have to ask again if something similar comes up.  If none of them have the effect you want then what you want is not possible without writing some sort of custom tool.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer